# The .Net framework 4.7 is not supported on this operation system

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework

I try to install .Net framework 4.7 but get me error that :

> The .Net framework 4.7 is not supported on this operation system

[image][image]

What is problem? How can i fix this?

Comment: You need to update Windows 10, as your version is very much out-of-date.

Comment: Build 1511 was out of support more than a year ago now and you should upgrade. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Net 4.7 is supported by a minimum of build 1607 of Windows 10: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3186497/the-net-framework-4-7-offline-installer-for-windows

Windows 10 build 1511 went out of support more than a year ago and is not supported by Microsoft or any of their products: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853

The solution is that you need to update Windows 10 and keep it up to date.

Comment: Can I do this with enable windows update? or I should reinstall up to date OS?

Comment: I would clean install the latest version.

Comment: Unless you have a VERY compelling reason to do so, you should leave Windows Update enabled and alone so that it can keep your computer up to date. Yes, you can update from 1511 to 1809 using Windows Update.